# Redireccionar a una página con un select

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que deseo es que al hacer clic en el botón

```
<a href="" class="button_dw_c w-button" onclick="enlace()">Conozca nuestras soluciones</a></div>
```

Se vaya a la página que este seleccionada en el `select`, la `URL` viene en el `value`.

```
    <select class="dropdown_dw_c w-dropdown">
            <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
            <?php 
            while(has_sub_field('dropdown')):
            $titulo_dw = get_sub_field('titulo_de_opcion');
            $link_dw = get_sub_field('enlace_de_opcion');
            ?>

            <option value="<?php  echo $link_dw;?>"><?php  echo $titulo_dw;?></option>

        <?php endwhile; ?>



    </select>
```

Intente esto pero no me funciono.

```
<script>
function enlace(value) {
  if (value != "") { location.href = value; }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que no estas buscando el valor seleccionado en el `select`.

### Solución:

- Es necesario poder identificar el `select`. Para esto yo uso la clase `w-dropdown` (podría usar cualquier otra). *Debes asegurarte de que no exista otro `select` con dicha clase*.
- El primer `option` debe tener un `value=""`, de lo contrario, el `value` seria igual al texto dentro de este (*eg: Seleccione una opción*)

#### Demo:

```js
function enlace() {
  // Buscamos el select y el valor del mismo
  var value = document.getElementsByClassName('w-dropdown')[0].value;
  if (value != "") { location.href = value; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="button_dw_c w-button" onclick="enlace()">Conozca nuestras soluciones</a>
</div>


<select class="dropdown_dw_c w-dropdown">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option><?php 

    while(has_sub_field('dropdown')):
    $titulo_dw = get_sub_field('titulo_de_opcion');
    $link_dw = get_sub_field('enlace_de_opcion'); ?>
    <option value="<?php  echo $link_dw;?>"><?php  echo $titulo_dw;?></option><?php
    
    endwhile; ?>
</select>
```